# FileMaker Pro 10 - How to Extract Layout and Scripts from fp7 File?

Tags: filemaker

I want to start tracking my FileMaker changes in Subversion but all I have a big binary file with everything.  Is there a way to extract the layout and script parts into a text format so that I can see diffs of what was changed?

I'm thinking maybe there's a 3rd party tool for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the closest thing you're going to find is FileMaker Pro Advanced's Database Design Report, which will export an XML or HTML representation of all of the elements in a FileMaker database. The report will include all of the script steps for a file and all of the position and other information for the layout objects, but depending on the size of your FileMaker system, it may take a while to generate each time.

I use version control for my FileMaker systems but don't bother with diffs, just making sure that I provide adequate comments for my commits.

Comment: That sounds perfect!  How long do you think it would take to run for a file that has about 10 tables, and 10 layouts, and a couple of scripts?  The file does have a lot of data though, it's 922MB.

Comment: For something that small, it should run pretty quickly. That amount of data doesn't matter, since it's only reporting on the structure of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [FMDiff](http://www.fmdiff.com/). It reads the original filemaker files (without needing to generate a DDR) and shows differences between multiple versions of the same file. I've not used it before, but always intended to.